# I'm tracking file downloads with GA, and I want to access the downloads data from another software

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

The main question here is really: is there a way to create an XML/JSON feed from GA data, so I could access it from another software?

Or alternatively, can the GA API allow accessing data like the "file downloads" events?

Answer (score 0):

The [google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) is quite extensive and allows you to download the data stored your your google analytics profile.   This data is downloaded by dimensions, and metrics across a date range.

If you are inserting event data for your google analytics account then yes the [event](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=event_tracking) data should be available.

```
{
  "reportRequests":[
  {
    "viewId":"XXXX",
    "dateRanges":[
      {
        "startDate":"2015-06-15",
        "endDate":"2015-06-30"
      }],
    "metrics":[
      {
        "expression":"ga:sessions"
      }],
    "dimensions": [
      {
        "name":"ga:browser"
      }]
    }]
}
```